# Parsing a value in powershell

Tags: parsing, powershell

So I run this command

```
$driverRAIDv = $data|where-object{$_.Name -eq "$serverName" -and ($_.Description1 -match "hpsa")} | select -ExpandProperty version
```

And it returns this value:

`HP HPSA Driver (v 5.0.0-28OEM)`

I want to take this value/variable and parse it so that I only have `5.0.0-28OEM`

Comment: will the text "HP HPSA Driver (v " always be in the string?

Comment: @Jimbo yes, I believe so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, matches anything between `(` and `)` brackets:

EDIT: ..and removes the v followed by a space:

```powershell
$driverRAIDv = $data|where-object{$_.Name -eq "$serverName" -and ($_.Description1 -match "hpsa")} | select -ExpandProperty version
$regex = "(?<=\().*(?=\))"
[regex]::matches($driverRAIDv,$regex).Value -replace "v "
```

which returns:

```powershell
5.0.0-28OEM
```

or you could use following regex which will match anything between `(v` and `)`

```powershell
$regex="(?<=\(v\s).*(?=\))"
```

Comment: This works wonders! Except there's no easy way to get rid of the "v" im guessing.. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. Basically, we're creating a "calculated property" that contains an expression to parse out the portion of the value that you want.

```
$driverRAIDv = $data|where-object{$_.Name -eq "$serverName" -and ($_.Description1 -match "hpsa")} | select -Property @{ Label = 'Version'; Expression = { [void]($_ -match ('v\s(.*?)\)')); $matches[1]; }; };
```

I tested this out using the following code:

```
@{ Version = 'HP HPSA Driver (v 5.0.0-28OEM)'} | select -Property @{ Label = 'Version'; Expression = { [void]($_ -match ('v\s(.*?)\)')); $matches[1]; }; };
```

If you check out the help for the `Select-Object` command, you will see that you can create calculated properties, which basically modify the value of a property, through a PowerShell expression. To do this, create a `Hashtable` that contains two items: `Label` and `Expression`. The `Label` can simply be set to the same property value that you're modifying. The `Expression` is a PowerShell `ScriptBlock` that performs some type of operation, and returns a result. In the example I gave above, we are running a regular expression against the `Version` property, and returning it as the result.

[image]

Comment: I tried to use this example. I've had no luck. It might be because I don't fully understand whats happening.. If you have time could you explain it a little more?

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to do it depending on your needs and variance of what you will get.

One way could be to use replace operator. Say, you got

```
$driverRAIDv="HP HPSA Driver (v 5.0.0-28OEM)"
$driverRAIDv -replace 'HP HPSA Driver \(v ','' -replace '\)',''
```

would get you 5.0.0-28OEM

In the same line:

```
$driverRAIDv = ($data|where-object{$_.Name -eq "$serverName" -and ($_.Description1 -match "hpsa")} | select -ExpandProperty version) -replace 'HP HPSA Driver \(v ','' -replace '\)',''
```

Comment: I tried the line you provided and it errors out with `Regular expression pattern is not valid: HP HPSA Driver (v .` Otherwise though it looks simple to use.

Comment: @krousemw , hmm, my comment on the update did not make it I guess, but I had updated the line. All you have to do is to escape paranthesis as they have special meaning in regex

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex option would be to split on `(`, `)` and  (space), and select the last non-empty string.

```
$driverRAIDv = $data|
    where {$_.Name -eq $serverName -and $_.Description1 -match "hpsa"} |
    foreach {$_.version.split('[() ]')| where {$_}| select -last 1}
```